# the 'this' key word with IIFE in javascript

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I was practicing java script from one of the book's examples and encounter following

**Code one**: here i learnt 'this' key word in javascript references the object that owns the code where 'this' keyword is.

```
function Vehicle1(theYear, theMake, theModel) {
    var year = theYear;
    var make = theMake;
    var model = theModel;
    this.getYear = function () { return year; };
    this.getMake = function () { return make; };
    this.getModel = function () { return model; };
}

Vehicle1.prototype.getInfo = function () {
    return 'Vehicle1: ' + this.getYear() + ' ' + this.getMake() + ' ' + this.getModel();
}
```

**Code two**: here i was learning about cretaing namespace using IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression).

```
(function () {
    this.myApp = this.myApp || {};
    var ns = this.myApp;

    var vehicleCount = 5;
    var vehicles = new Array();

    ns.Car = function () { };
    ns.Truck = function () { };

    var repair = {
        description: 'changed spark plugs',
        cost: 100
    };
} ());
```

I was supposed to execute above codes individually to understand the concepts that the author was trying to explain. But i ended up executing both codes in single file, and i am getting error message in code one stating

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function Vehicle1.getInfo.myApp

Question is: Why or how the IIFE function is trying to put or finding myApp namespace in code one ?

if i execute above 2 codes individually all works as expected.

**EDIT**
Here is full code just copy past it in html's head section using script tags. I run it in chrome and look in console for error details

```
function Vehicle1(theYear, theMake, theModel) {
        var year = theYear;
        var make = theMake;
        var model = theModel;
        this.getYear = function () { return year; };
        this.getMake = function () { return make; };
        this.getModel = function () { return model; };
    };

    Vehicle1.prototype.getInfo = function () {
        return 'Vehicle1: ' + this.getYear() + ' ' + this.getMake() + ' ' + this.getModel();
    }


    (function () {
        this.myApp = this.myApp || {};
        var ns = this.myApp;

        var vehicleCount = 5;
        var vehicles = new Array();

        ns.Car = function () { };
        ns.Truck = function () { };

        var repair = {
            description: 'changed spark plugs',
            cost: 100
        };
    } ());
```

Comment: _"I learnt 'this' key word references the object that owns the code where 'this' keyword is."_ -- Not quite. `this` is nothing until you call the function. The magic happens with `new`. `this` will depend on **how** you call the function.

Comment: Were you creating a `Vehicle1` and if so were you using the `new` operator? Because it sounds like you just typed `Vehicle1()` instead of `new Vehicle1()`.

Comment: can you post the "combined" code the gave you this error?  on it's own, the 2nd snippet should be fine

Comment: I think the error will be fixed if you add a semi-colon before snippet 2: `;(function () {` in the combined code.

Comment: @user815923: Yes, the ';' fixed the issue.

Comment: @RobertLevy: I just updated question, and that is all i have in my <script> tag and there is nothing else in html body.

Comment: @MikeC: Yes, i was using new operator just to create objects of Vehicle1 in test scripts using QUnit.

Comment: @elclanrs I guess i understand what you are saying (hopefully!!). But when i run just code one no issues, when i add code two it runs into issue code two has nothing to do with code one right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error because of a missing semicolon after the first code, causing the combined file to be interpreted in a very different way than intended.

Let's simplify the code to see the structure. You have something like:

```
getInfo = function () {
    this.getYear();
}

(function () {
    this.myApp = {};
} ());
```

Without the semicolon after the first function, the parenthesis around the second function are treated as giving the parameters to call the first function:

```
getInfo = function () {
    this.getYear();
}(function () {
    this.myApp = {};
} ());
```

So it's basically as if you wrote:

```
function getInfo() {
    this.getYear();
}

getInfo(function () {
    this.myApp = {};
}());
```

`this` in both these cases refers to the `Window` (or the global object) because the function is not being called on an instance. You're calling the second function, which will set `Window.myApp`, then passing its return value (undefined) to `getInfo`. `getInfo` will access `this.getYear` which doesn't exist so you get the type error.

The error I get here, and with your original code is:

> TypeError: this.getYear is not a function

Because `this` is the global object, then `this.getYear` is going to be undefined (not a function).

Comment: finally somebody answering the question :)

Comment: @fgb Thank you for detailed explanation. As per 'javascript the good parts' by 'douglas crockford', Shouldn't the javascript engine(compiler or parser) put semicolons for us ?

Comment: @venu Semicolons are usually automatically inserted but there are a few ambiguous cases like this where they aren't. If you don't use semicolons, you need to be careful with lines beginning with `(`, `[`, `+`, `-`, `/`.

Answer (score 4):

> i learned 'this' key word in javascript references the object that owns the code where 'this' keyword is.

That is not the case, but it seems kind of like it is.

*Warning - the following will sound stupid. That is because javascript `this` is a really bad language feature (and people should stop using it).*

Here's the deal - there's not really such a thing as `this`. At least not in the way you think it is. It's really a function parameter just like any other.

Let me show you.

let's say you have a function like this

```
function sayHi(firstName, lastName) {
    console.log("Hi", firstName, " ", lastName);
}
```

Here's two different but pretty much identical ways to invoke it:

```
sayHi("Fred", "Flintstone");
sayHi.call(null, "Fred", "Flintstone");
```

this is because all functions have a `call` method. If you want to, you can write all your function invocations by using `.call`.

But what's that first `null` parameter? Well, that parameter is what `this` will be set to. So if you have:

```
function sayHi(lastName) {
    console.log("Hi", this, " ", lastName);
}
```

you can say

```
sayHi.call("Fred", "Flintstone");
```

So now let me ask you a question. If you can always write all functions using `.call`, and if `.call` takes `this` as a parameter right next to the others, how exactly is `this` different from any other parameter? Just one that you don't get to name.

But what does the `sayHi(...)` format do with `this` then? Since we're not specifying it directly it must come from somewhere. Well, in this form - which is really just a facade for `call` - javascript **takes a guess** at what you want it to be. The rules aren't terribly complex, but it's still pretty confusing.

If you're invoking it as an object

```
var fred = "Fred";
fred.sayHi = sayHi;
fred.sayHi("Flintstone");
```

is equivalent to

```
fred.sayHi.call(fred, "Flintstone");
```

In the case of invoking it directly:

```
sayHi("Flintstone");
```

the rules dictate that it will guess that `this` is the global `window` object. Unless you're in strict mode, in which case it will be `undefined` (I think, it might be `null`).

```
sayHi.call(window, "Flintstone");
```

This is what is going on with an IIFE.

Basically, `this` is a feature that was tacked on to make it look more like Java and is really not necessary for the language at all. Some libraries use it, and you don't have a choice, but I always consult people that when they have control of it [they don't use `this` or `new` (which is even more confusing)](http://togakangaroo.github.io/2014/04/29/on-this-and-new.html) at all.

Answer (score 2):

The `this` keyword in JavaScript is whatever is calling or executing the function.  In your example, for a IIFE, `this` would be the global `Window` object AKA `window`

Your question seems to be missing code.  Are `Car` and `Truck` supposed to extend `Vehicle1` or something?

And you have no code calling `Vehicle1.getInfo.myApp`, so I'm not sure how you could be getting that message.

Comment: No code is missing. The only thing missing is QUnit's test scripts which reside in some other files. As i said, i was supposed to execute them in individual files to learn what the author was trying to explain.